# Divide $(x+1)^8+4(x+1)^6+6(x+1)^4+4(x+1)^2+1$ by $x^2+2x+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Divide $(x+1)^8+4(x+1)^6+6(x+1)^4+4(x+1)^2+1$ by $x^2+2x+2$

I'm stuck. I don't think I apply the binomial theorem and open up every bracket and manually calculate. $x^2+2x+2$ can be written as $x^2+2(x+1)$, but what do I do with the $x^2$ and $2$ terms? So this doesn't seem the way. I could rewrite the dividend as $(x+1)^2[(x+1)^6+4(x+1)^4+6(x+1)^2+4]+1$, but this looks to me hardly divisible by $x^2+2x+2$.

There must be a trick or short-cut to do with $(x+1)$, but I can't see it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't the sequence $1,4,6,4,1$ ring any bell?

Comment: If you don't catch the easy way @dxiv hinted at, you could try doing a transformation to $y=x+1$ and see what you get.

Comment: $[(x+1)^2+1]^4$? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, $x^2+2x+2 = (x+1)^2 + 1$, so if we set $t=(x+1)^2$, our task is to divide
$$ t^4 + 4t^3 + 6t^2 + 4 t + 1 = (t+1)^4$$
by $t+1$....